# How to get all materials of children game objects unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So what I want to do is when enemys get hit they flash red for a second and then, go back to their base materials. Here's the code!

```
    public float Health;

    public AudioSource Src;
    public AudioClip HurtClip;
    public GameObject DeathEffect;

    void Start()
    {
        Src = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    public void TakeDamage(float amount)
    {
        StartCoroutine(FlashRed());

        Src.PlayOneShot(HurtClip);
        Health -= amount;
        if (Health <= 0f)
        {
            Death();
        }
    }

    void Death()
    {
        Instantiate(DeathEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    IEnumerator FlashRed()
    {
        Renderer[] ts = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
        foreach (Renderer t in ts)
        {
            t.material.color = Color.red;
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.14f);

        foreach (Renderer t in ts)
        {
            t.material.color = Color.white; 
        }
    }
}
```

I dont want them to turn white. I want to get their base materials and turn them to that

Comment: As far as I see from the code, the question in the title is not what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would save the color value before making them red. And then restore the value in the end of the coroutine.

P.S.: You would need to add using for Linq in the start of the script file.

```
IEnumerator FlashRed()
{
    Renderer[] ts = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();

    var prevColors = ts.Select(t => t.material.color);
    
    foreach (Renderer t in ts)
    {
        t.material.color = Color.red;
    }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.14f);

    for (int i = 0; i < ts.Count(); i++)
    {
        t.material.color = prevColors[i];
    }
}
```